# Replacing floor operation with modulus

Tags: modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have this array of characters

> aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkllllllllllmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnooooooooooppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrrrssssssssssttttttttttuuuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzz

it's the alphabet in order, with 10 of each character, so that's 260 characters.

Given an index between 0 and 259, how can I create a function that can return the expected letter with only knowledge of the alphabet itself (a-z)?

One simple way would be:

```
index_of_letter = floor(index/10);
```

so if index is 9, it would yield floor(.9), which is 0, which would be the letter `a` in the standard western alphabet. If the index was 259, that would yield floor(25.9) which would in turn yield z.

However, isn't there a way to do this with `modulus` instead of using a `floor` operator?

I can't figure out how to do this with mod, but I am sure there is away to do! Anyone know how I could do this with mod?

Comment: $\operatorname{floor}(x) = x - [x\pmod 1]$ so $\operatorname{floor}(x/10) = x/10 - [(x/10) \pmod 1]$.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. For positive $x, k$ integers, and % being the usual mod operator

```
floor(x/k) = (x - x % k)/k
```

As dxiv notes, this might be redundant (depending on the language you're using) - often, for integer types, $x/y$ is already a $floor$ operation.

One issue here is that various languages will disagree about the results when $x<0$. For example some languages believe $(-1)$ % $3 = -1$; while others insist that $(-1)$ % $3 = 2$. So that should be kept in mind.

Also, this relationship can be used when the language does not support % for non-integers; because

```
x % k = x - k*floor(x/k)
```

(again, keep track of what you want to happen with $x<0$).

Comment: thanks this works fine, I was wondering - there most be a different way to do this using mod and 26 as our magic number. A pure translation from floor to mod is nice, but just looking for another way to do it, just for kicks

Comment: Happy to be of assistance; I work in a number of languages, and sometimes I use this trick when I'm on a roll only because I can't remember whether / in that language uses floor or round :). Please remember to accept this answer if it answers your question!

Answer (score 2):

If the language is `C` or `Java` by any chance, and if `index` is an integer variable (not floating point), then all you need to do is:

```
index_of_letter = index / 10;
```

since the `/` operator performs integer division with truncation (for non-negative operands), so taking the `floor` of the result is redundant.